# Image file not found

Tags: texstudio

I was developing a document in `Latex` using `TexStudio` that was installed in `windows7` and now I want to continue in `Ubuntu`. I installed Latex in Ubuntu and compiled my same project but I got error

```
! LaTeX Error: File `./DFKI_logo' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.26 ...raphics[width=0.55\textwidth]{./DFKI_logo}
                                              ~\\[1cm]
I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

Comment: Is it `pdflatex` or `latex` you are using? What format does your `DFKI_logo` have? Is it an `.pdf` file? In that case, you cannot compile with `latex`.

Comment: Note that `_` in file names often cause problems.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am using `pdflatex` BTW I have also tried `latex`. Image file format is `.jpg`

Comment: @SeanAllred I tried after removing underscore but in vain.

Comment: @SeanAllred: I use `_` often, without problems

Comment: @wafeeq: And your graphics file is in the same directory where your document `.tex` can be found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it was working in Windows 7 and stopped working under Ubuntu, most probably you have incorrect case in the name of the file. For example `DFKI_logo.pdf` and `dfki_logo.pdf` for Windows are the same (most of the time anyway), for Ubuntu they are not. Check if you have the file name correct including case of the letters.

Comment: I have `miktex`in windows and 'texlive` in ubuntu

Comment: You are right. In `Linux` things are case sensitive. Problem solved